# Не работает код HTML + JS

Tags: javascript, html

Коллеги, добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, почему при нажатии на кнопку, которую я зарегистрировал в JS не работает тот самый код? Что я делаю не так?

```js
const langbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.header__lang-btn');

for (let i = 0; i < langbtn.length; i++) {
  langbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //alert('Test!');
    console.log('Test!');
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="header__langs">
  <button class="header__lang-btn">ru</button>
  <button class="header__lang-btn lang-active">en</button>
</div>
```

Сам скрипт подключен корректно, тестовое сообщение при загрузке сайта выводит, но не работает алерт при клике на одну из зарегистрированных кнопок, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я не стал править ошибку. Посмотри на что ты вешаешь обработчик `langbtn`, а надо `langbtn[i]`

Comment: Что лучше, langbtn[i].onclick, или как в моем коде через addEventListener?

Comment: Это совершенно разные вещи, в `langbtn` у вас коллекция, а в `langbtn[i]` - конкретный элемент

Comment: Оба этих метода (onclick  и addEventListener) в этом коде должны работать одинаково.

Comment: @Андрей всегда предпочитаю `addEventListener`.

Comment: Спасибо всем, все заработало)))